# Given a graph how can I come up with positions for the nodes so that the cliques in the graph are close?

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx, graph-theory

I have a very large graph in NetworkX and I am trying to plot it out. I have calculated the maximal cliques. My problem is that there are way too many nodes, connections and that I want each maximal clique in the graph to be close together in the plot so that it does not look cluttered.

Is there a known solution to this problem? Can I somehow find good positions on a 2D plane for the nodes?

Comment: Honestly, if you come up with a solution, then please tell me. Even finding the maximal clique in a graph is np complete, so I don't think there is anything ready-made for that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem

Comment: There are many tools for graph visualization. See a few: https://python-graph-gallery.com/network-chart/

Comment: @Stef Thank you. Apparently there are algorithms for node positioning provided in NetworkX. This website is great.